# Ping selected IPs from checkbox on PHP-MySQL query

Tags: php, select, checkbox, mysqli, ping

[image: please see picture for more details]

I have an idea and wonder if it can be or not on PHP since I'm new to PHP. I need to ping selected computer name or IP address and give me the status on ping status box as online or offline.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Books</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="Untitled-1.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search"/>

<input type="submit" value="search"/>
<input type="button"value="ping"/>

</form>

</form>
<br/>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>desktop</th>
            <th>ip address</th>
            <th>select pc's</th>
            <th>ping status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    include("db.php");
    $word = isset ($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : "";
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pc WHERE desktop like '%$word%'");
    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $test['user_id']; 
        ?>
        <tr align='center'>
            <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['username'] ?></font></td>
            <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['desktop'] ?> </font></td>
            <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['ip_address'] ?></font></td>
            <td><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
            <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['ping_status'] ?></font></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Pass ip in this function it give status of host.

```
 <?php

    function ping_host($host){
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $host, $output, $result);
     return $result==0?"online":"offline";

    }

    echo ping("www.google.com"); // function call

   ?>
```

Note:Here 4 is number of ping you want you can change according to requirement in linux system if you not set this it will ping forever.

Comment: thanks but i already know about this function , but im wonder if  it can be with query , or atleast ping button beside each line on the query

Comment: you can do in query or ping button as you wish but in query case if there is more record in table then it will take time to load page if internet connection is slow if it is local network then no problem.

Comment: ok can you help me how can i do it by button beside each one on the query, so i can ping just the line which have the button

Comment: you can get ip address of selected pc using checkbox  which is checked on ping button click .on ping button click you can  submit form or use  ajax   if you do not want to  refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

thanks alot Sunil for try to help me , i found the selution and it's work fine with me now

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<?php
require("db.php");

?>


<body>


<form method="post">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                <strong><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i></strong>
                            </div>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                
                                    <th>username</th>
                                    <th>desktop</th>
                                    <th>ip address</th>
                                    <th>select</th>
                                     <th>status</th>

                                  
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <?php 
       $query=mysql_query("select * from pc")or die(mysql_error());
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $id=$row['ip_address'];
              
       
       ?>
                                
          <tr>

        <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['desktop'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ip_address'] ?></td>
                                        <td>
<input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">          </td>  

<td><?php echo $row['ping_status'] ?></td>
                                </tr>
                         <?php  }
 

      
              
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 
if(!empty($_POST['selector'])){
     foreach($_POST['selector'] as $id){
   
  
  
  if (!$socket = @fsockopen($id, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) 



{ $status= "offline";
echo $status; } 

else 


{ $status= "online";
echo $status;

 fclose($socket); } 
 

 
$sql="UPDATE pc SET ping_status='$status' WHERE ip_address='$id'";

$query=mysql_query($sql);

  header("Location:test.php"); 
 }
 }
}
 ?>
 
 
       
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
      
<button class="btn btn-success"  name="submit" type="submit">
ping
</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please find the last solution ,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<?php
require("db.php");

?>


<body>


<form method="post">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                <strong><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i></strong>
                            </div>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                
                                    <th>username</th>
                                    <th>desktop</th>
                                    <th>ip address</th>
                                    <th>select</th>
                                     <th>status</th>

                                  
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <?php 
       $query=mysql_query("select * from pc")or die(mysql_error());
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $id=$row['ip_address'];
              
       
       ?>
                                
          <tr>

        <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['desktop'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ip_address'] ?></td>
                                        <td>
<input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">          </td>  

<td><?php echo $row['ping_status'] ?></td>
                                </tr>
                         <?php  }
 

  $sql1="UPDATE pc
SET ping_status = NULL
WHERE ping_status is not null";
$query1=mysql_query($sql1);

  
  

      function pingAddress($id) {
    $pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 $id  && exit", $output, $result);
    //echo $result. "<br/>";
global $status;

    if (($result == 0)){
        if(count(preg_grep('/Destination host unreachable/i', $output)) == 0){
            $status="online <br/>";
   echo $status;
   
  
  }else
 $status="offline <br/>";
   echo $status; 
   
     }
    elseif ($result == 1){
$status="offline <br/>";
   echo $status;
     
   
   
   }    
}


     
              
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 
if(!empty($_POST['selector'])){
     foreach($_POST['selector'] as $id){

 
 

   
  echo $id."";
  


 pingAddress($id);

$sql="UPDATE pc SET ping_status='$status' WHERE ip_address='$id'";

$query=mysql_query($sql);


 header("Location:test.php");


}

 }

}
 ?>
 
 
       
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
      
<button class="btn btn-success"  name="submit" type="submit">
ping
</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```